# How to send push notifications to android when app is closed

Tags: android, notifications, push

I have a very simple app made with android studio, an web viewer for my forum app. I integrated push notfications to be able to send notifications like "Hi! There are some new subjects on our forum, check it out" and make people open the app. I followed the exact documentation from here https://pushbots.com/developer/docs/android-sdk-integration
I am now able to send notifications to all the users that have my application. My problem is that they dont see the notification unless they have the application opened. For example, if I test it and send a push notification, but i dont have the app opened, i wont receive anything. I want to be able to send notifications even if they have the app closed, that's my point, i want to make them open the app to see the new questions on my forum
What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of what was formerly known as [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) and is now known as [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/). Can push messages to user phone even when app is closed